# Assignment to a list function not working

Tags: python, list, average

I am trying to solve a simple problem. Enter three numbers and find the average of the largest two.

```
while True:
    try:
        n1 = int(input("Enter n1: "))
        n2 = int(input("Enter n2: "))
        n3 = int(input("Enter n3: "))
    except ValueError:
        print ("Enter an integer: ") 
        continue
    else:
        break
mylist = [n1,n2,n3]
mylist.remove(min(mylist))
print (float(sum(mylist))/2)
```

Why is this not working. If I remove the assignment n_avg and keep the last two lines of code as shown below it works. Can someone explain why?

```
mylist.remove(min(mylist))
print (float(sum(mylist))/2)
```

Comment: Did you mean `mylist = [n1,n2,n3]` line? You are creating list and remove method, min method and sum methods are supported methods for lists.

Comment: "not working" is not a problem specification.  Also, `n_avg` does not appear in your code.  I'm unclear on the problem.  The code works fine for me.

Comment: I do not see any problem with the code. What is *not working*?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion everyone. I was trying the write the code as              
       n_avg = mylist.remove(min(mylist)) and then print the average of n_avg. If I assign the action on mylist, the code pops the error: 'NoneType' object is not iterable. Why os that so?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to share a slightly cleaner code.

```
mylist = []
while len(mylist) < 3:
    try:
        mylist.append(int(input("Enter a number:")))
    except ValueError:
        print ("Please enter an integer") 

mylist.remove(min(mylist))
print (sum(mylist)/2.)
```

Works as expected.